# In-App HTTP monitoring in android non-rooted device

Tags: android, proxy, http-monitor

Is there any way for an Android application that it can **monitor** its own **HTTP requests-responses**?

I have used [**Charles**](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) proxy tool, works well, but can we have any in-app solution?
Apps like [**wireshark**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark&hl=en) accesses TCP/IP packets using tcpdump Linux tool, but it requires root access.

If somehow I create a proxy local port programatically and keep listening on that, maybe I can achieve what I need; but obviously configuring network programatically to set proxy requires root. [I checked [**ProxyDroid**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) app, which lets us set proxy]

I don't see **any way for a non-rooted device** if I could monitor at-least my own app's http stuff. Logging HTTP requests/responses manually is not what I want. [**TrafficStats**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) API provides info about number of bytes|packets received|transmitted, not more detailed monitoring of even our own calls.

Any sort of clarification/confirmation/suggestion is welcome.